# Who is the girl who takes William's place in the alternate timeline?

Tags: life-is-strange

In *Life is Strange*, when Max saves Chloe’s dad William from his fatal car accident using time travel, her actions unintentionally create an alternate timeline where a girl suffers a car accident of her own that renders her quadriplegic, irreversibly damages her respiratory system, and is slowly killing her as her parents struggle to get money to make her final days more comfortable. Eventually, the girl begs Max to kill her.

Who is this random stranger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That girl is Chloe.

> Chloe's previous history as an archetypal punk rocker has seemingly been wiped out completely in the new timeline Max created in "Chaos Theory" by preventing the death of Chloe's father, William. She is now restricted to an electric wheelchair which assists with movement, as well as being dependent on a breathing apparatus. This is due to a car accident that Chloe was involved in sometime before March 2011 after William had bought her a vehicle for her 16th birthday. An SUV cut her off, and she crashed, tragically snapping her spine and paralyzing herself. Chloe also has severe troubles with her respiratory system, and is deteriorating quickly. The complete collapse of her respiratory system is inevitable, according to her doctor. Her parents decide not to tell her, ignoring the advice of the doctor. However, Chloe is fully aware of the situation, having heard the doctors discussing it while she was pretending to be asleep.

https://life-is-strange.fandom.com/wiki/Chloe_Price#Alternative_Timeline